# separating functions/files in node and callbacks

Tags: node.js, express, callback

I am trying to organise my code in 3 files

- basic_routes.js
- general_functions.js
- db_queries.js

so that for a `GET` request, I can respond with the resulting rows. I am simply unable to wrap my head around the callback functions. How can I return the resulting rows to the client ?

File: db_queries.js

```
function getUserData (userId, fn){
    client.query("select * from participationTable where ? in (userId1, userId2)", userId, function(err,rows){
        if (err) {
            return fn(new Error('(customError) unable to find ongoing games'));
        } else {
            return fn(null, rows);
        }
    });
}
module.exports.getUserData = getUserData;
```

File: general_functions.js

```
var db = require('./db_queries');
function getUserParticipationDeatils(req, function(err, rows){
    db.getUserData(req.user.userId, function(err, rows){
            if (err){ return done(err); }
            // 'rows' is accessible here
            // but how can I send it ?
        });
});
module.exports.getUserParticipationDeatils = getUserParticipationDeatils;
```

File: basic_routes.js

```
var general_functions = require('./general_functions');
app.get('/getUserParticipation', function (req, res) {  
    general_functions.getUserParticipationDeatils(req, function(err, rows){
        if (err){ return done(err); }
        return res.send(JSON.stringify(rows));
    }); 
});
```

Please help me structure the functions in the file general_functions.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your getUserParticipationDeatils to accept a callback fn just like your getUserData function.

Something like this:

```
var db = require('./db_queries');
function getUserParticipationDeatils(req, fn){
    db.getUserData(req.user.userId, function(err, rows){
        if (err){ return fn(err); }
        fn(null, rows);
    });
});
module.exports.getUserParticipationDeatils = getUserParticipationDeatils;
```

Comment: You don't need to create an anonymous callback function yourself here, just do `db.getUserData(req.user.userId, fn)`;

Comment: @idbehold Agreed. That was just to demonstrate the OP how to handle callbacks.

Comment: Thank you, both. Also, when would you use `next` here: `app.get('/getUserParticipation', function (req, res, next){...}` and would that mean using `if(err){return next(err)` instead of `if (err){ return fn(err);` ?